# How to link up to pages in django

Tags: django, django-views

What I need to do is, I need to go to a list view to another list view. But I need to filter the later list view with the clicked link. What is the filter attribute then?

I have a student model with batch (sbtc), I need to pass the later list view with a filter of selected batch.

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class FindStudent(ListView):
    template_name = 'Dashboard/findStudent.html'
    model = Student
    fields = ['sbtc']

    def get_queryset(self):
        batch = Student.objects.values_list('sbtc').distinct()
        return batch

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class FindStudentdetail(ListView):
    template_name = 'Dashboard/findStudentdetail.html'
    model = Student
    fields = ['all']

    def get_queryset(self):
        student = Student.objects.filter(sbtc=#here what will be)
        return student
```

Comment: Did you checkout this https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ ?

Comment: Went through a bit, but could not get the sol.

Answer (score 0):

In your template, you can just add a link to the `findStudentDetail` template; here's a modified example from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/):

```
<h1>Articles</h1>
<ul>
{% for article in object_list %}
    <li>{{ article.pub_date|date }} - {{ article.headline }}</li>\
    <a href="/articleDetail.html?smbc={{article.smbc}}">View Detail</a>
{% empty %}
    <li>No articles yet.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Then, in the response view, you can just get the GET parameter with `kwargs`:

```
class FindStudentdetail(ListView):
    template_name = 'Dashboard/findStudentdetail.html'
    model = Student
    fields = ['all']

    def get_queryset(self):
        student = Student.objects.filter(sbtc=self.kwargs['sbtc'])
        return student
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    student = Student.objects.filter(sbtc=self.kwargs['pk'])
    return student
```